# Download Excel file into Unprotected View

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am running a website written in ASP.net and any Excel file you download gets downloaded in `Protected View`. This causes an extra few clicks for the user to be able to edit it.

How can I alter this so the files always are downloaded in `Unprotected View`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible IF you have control over the computers who can download from your website. Than you can add your website to the trusted websites and everything will work fine.
How to do it, you have to google - our Admins had to google a lot to find it out, and I do not know the details :/

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following links:

- Disable Protected View in Office 2010,
  https://amsterdam.jira.com/wiki/display/MAN/How+to+disable+protected+view+in+Excel+2010
- Disable Protected View in Office 2007 and 2010 by using Trust
  Settings,
  http://helpmerick.com/solution-to-microsoft-outlook-2007-or-2010-not-opening-word-or-excel-attachments.htm
- How to edit your Excel settings.
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx

**What is Protected View?**

*"Files from the Internet and from other potentially unsafe locations can contain viruses, worms, or other kinds of malware, which can harm your computer. To help protect your computer, files from these potentially unsafe locations are opened in Protected View. By using Protected View, you can read a file and inspect its contents while reducing the risks that can occur."*

**Why is my file opening in Protected View?**

*Protected View is a read-only mode in which most editing functions have been disabled. There are several reasons why a file opens in Protected View:*

***The file was opened from an Internet location** - When you see the message in Protected View that states This file originated from an Internet location and might be unsafe. Click for more details., this is because the file is being opened from the Internet. Files from the Internet can have viruses and other harmful content embedded in them. We recommend that you edit only the document, if you trust its contents.*

***The file was received as an Outlook 2010 attachment and your computer policy has defined the sender as unsafe** - When you encounter the message in Protected View that states This file originated as an e-mail attachment and might be unsafe. Click for more details., this is because the file was received from a potentially unsafe sender.*

***The file was opened from an unsafe location** - When you encounter the message in Protected View that states This file was opened from a potentially unsafe location. Click for more details. the file was opened from a folder that is unsafe. An example of an unsafe location is your Temporary Internet Files folder.*

***The file is blocked by File Block***

***File validation failure** - When you encounter a message in Protected View that states Office has detected a problem with this file. Editing it may harm your computer. Click for more details. It has occurred because the file did not pass file validation.*

***NOTE** - You can learn more about file validation failures in Problem detected with a file.
The file was opened in Protected View by using the Open in Protected View option.     When you encounter the message in Protected View that states This file was opened in Protected View. Click for more details., this is because you chose to open the file in Protected View. This can be done by using the Open in Protected View option: Click the File tab. In the Microsoft Office Backstage view, click Open. On the Open dialog box, click the arrow on the Open button. From the list, select Open in Protected View. The following image is an example of Protected View appearing when Open in Protected View is selected.
 IMPORTANT   System administrators can extend the list of potentially unsafe locations to include additional folders also considered unsafe."*

Comment: What I want is to have this configured in my application.  Meaning, there will be no configuration on the users' side.  Is that possible? thanks

Comment: Isn't this always configured locally? Each visitor will have different security settings enabled. So I doubt you'll be able to 'program' anything for this.